# Checkstyle ParenPad Check

Tags: java, checkstyle

I have a situation where Checkstyle is producing false positives on the ParenPad rule check. I also saw this SO article [Checkstyle: Usage of ParenPad Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048428/checkstyle-usage-of-parenpad-check) and this question is unrelated.

Consider the following code segment:

```
public class Foo

    public static final void main(      String... args ) { ... }

}
```

When ParenPad is configured like so:

```
<module name="ParenPad">
    <property name="option" value="space" />
</module>
```

This result will show as valid since there is *a* space before the opening `(` in the `main` method.

I was poking around in the ParenPad check class and I didn't see any other rules/configurations that could be used to enforce a *single* space before and/or after a parenthesis. Is there something built-in that allows me to enforce this requirement or do I need to create a custom check? From what I can tell, the current implementation checks for the existence for any number of spaces be it tab delimited or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the checkstyle code, the only way I see currently is by adding another check.
First you define the `ParenPad` and then you add two `RegexpSingleline`s

```
<module name="RegexpSingleline">
    <property name="format" value="(\s{2,}$"/>
    <property name="message" value="Too many spaces after ("/>
</module>
<module name="RegexpSingleline">
    <property name="format" value="\s{2,})$"/>
    <property name="message" value="Too many spaces before )"/>
</module>
```

True, it can break in other cases (e.g. a string that has a `(` or `)`), but you can extend it to cover majority of your cases.